# Replacing window.setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Guys,
   I'm thinking of replacing window.setTimeout with a function of my own (for example we could have a generic error handler for exceptions thrown in callbacks).

The code will be along these lines:

```
var nativeSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(fn, interval){
    nativeSetTimeout(function(){
            try{
               fn();
            }catch(e){
                // handle errors coming from the execution of fn
            }
        }, interval);
}
```

Given that my app will stay in a single iframe, is there any outstanding issue that I should be concerned about?

Comment: just add your own function that make a setTimeout and a calll back or anything u need. instead of overriding it

Comment: Not sure how your try/catch can work like in your example, you'll need an internal function to invoke fn and to put the timeout on that function, not the one in the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't do that because it's true it can help in your own development, but replacing standard functions could break third-party libraries.

Basically, using your own function without replacing standard one should be the way to go. Use it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do it that way, but unless you're deliberately trying to intercept the behaviour of existing code or third party libraries, it would be clearer to just write a wrapper with an alternative name, E.g. `function setSafeTimeout(fn, timeout) { ... ; return setTimeout(fn, timeout);}`.